# multiple inheritance in java : implementing interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a class that implements Comparator but not that I need my class to be Serializable 
How can I implement both of them  ?

```
public class A implements Comparator<A>
{
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: you want to implement Comparator and Serializable?

Comment: Oh never mind I got it

Comment: To expand on all of the answers, in Java you can only `extend` a single `class`, but you can `implement` unlimited interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misconception that Java does not have multiple inheritance. It doesn't have multiple inheritance of state, but it *does* have multiple inheritance of (declarations of) behavior, which is shown through interfaces. So you can have a single class implement multiple interfaces:

```
public class A implements Comparator<A>, Serializable {
}
```

Comment: Not quite right. It has multiple inheritance of **declarations of behavior**. Interfaces lack **implementation**, so it's not truly multiple inheritance of behavior. Essentially, it's a bridge between true multiple-inheritance and duck-typing.

Comment: Technically, it still (as of 7) doesn't have inheritance of behavior, but at least that's kinda changing.

Comment: I guess you two are technically correct, at least for a few more days until Java 8 comes out. I'll try to reword the answer.

Comment: @aruisdante I updated the answer in accordance with your comment. Downvoter: please see the revised answer.

Comment: @arshajii could you add more explanition about state and behavior, I don't understand how two are different ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class A implements Comparator<A>, Serializable {

    @Override
    public int compare(A arg0, A arg1) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement more than one interface, simply separate them with commas:

```
class A implements Comparator<A>, Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `extend` only one superclass but you can `implement` as many interfaces as you like, e.g.

```
public class A extends B implements Comparator<A>, Serializable {
}
```